Large in-memory raster calculations in PyQGIS
My workflow in a nutshell: I create cost rasters from starting points along a street network (grass7:r.cost), reclassify them according to their distance values (gdal:rastercalculator) and would like to add up all resulting rasters.
After trying to add up all at once I decided to iterate over, which also needs to happen in memory. However I just fail to make it work. The Input does not get accepted no matter if I use QgsRasterLayer or the direct output of the gdal calculation. Those are definitely valid.
    def process_layer(layer, output_prefix, sum_raster):
        heat_columns = ['0_100', '100_200', '200_300', '300_400']
        featurecounter = 0
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            point_id = feature.id()
            point_geom = feature.geometry()
            feedback.pushInfo(f"Processing Point ID: {point_id}, Geometry: {point_geom.asWkt()}")

            coords = point_geom.asPoint()
            x, y = coords.x(), coords.y()

            params = {
                'input': result['output'],
                '-k': False,
                '-n': False,
                'start_coordinates': f"{x},{y}",
                'max_cost': 400,
                'null_cost': None,
                'output': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
                'nearest': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
                'outdir': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
                'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER': 1,
                'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT': '',
                'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META': '',
                'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER': -1,
                'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER': 0.0001
            }

            cost_grid_result = processing.run('grass7:r.cost', params)
            if cost_grid_result and 'output' in cost_grid_result:
                cost_grid_raster = cost_grid_result['output']
            else:
                feedback.reportError(f"Failed to create cost raster for Point ID: {point_id}")

            # Retrieving heat values
            point_heat_values = [
                [column, feature[column]] if column in feature.fields().names() else [column, None]
                for column in heat_columns
            ]

            # Calculating raster based on heat values
            for key, value in point_heat_values:
                if value is None:  # Skip if value is None
                    continue
                a_key = key[:key.find("_")]
                b_key = key[key.find("_") + 1:]
                intvalue = int(value)

                try:
                    expression = f'((A > {a_key}) * (A <= {b_key}) * {intvalue}) + ((A <= {a_key}) + (A > {b_key})) * 0'
                    params = {
                        'FORMULA': expression,
                        'INPUT_A': cost_grid_raster,
                        'BAND_A': 1,
                        'RTYPE': 1,
                        'OUTPUT': f"memory:recalculated_raster_{point_id}_{key}_{value}"
                    }

                    recalculated_result = processing.run('gdal:rastercalculator', params)
                    recalculated_raster = recalculated_result['OUTPUT']

                    # SUMMING UP RASTERS ----------
                    if sum_raster is not None:
                        
                        #feedback.pushInfo(str(sum_raster))
                        #feedback.pushInfo(str(type(sum_raster)))
                        #sum_raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(sum_raster)

                        #feedback.pushInfo(str(recalculated_raster))
                        #feedback.pushInfo(str(type(recalculated_raster)))
                        #recalculated_raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(recalculated_raster)

                        params = {
                            'EXPRESSION': 'A + B',
                            'LAYERS': [sum_raster, recalculated_raster],
                            'BANDS': [1, 1],
                            'OUTPUT': 'memory:sum_result'
                        }
                        feedback.pushInfo(f"Params: {params}")
                        try:
                            sum_result = processing.run('native:virtualrastercalc', params)
                            sum_raster = sum_result['OUTPUT']

                        except Exception as e:
                            feedback.reportError(f"Exception occurred during sum_raster calculation: {str(e)}")
                    else:
                        sum_raster = recalculated_raster

                except Exception as e:
                    feedback.reportError(f"Exception occurred: {str(e)}")
                    break  # Exit the loop on failure

        return sum_raster

    # EXECUTING FUNCTION ----------
    sum_raster = None
    for layer_name in plugin_updated_list:
        layer = results[layer_name]
        output_prefix = layer.name()
        sum_raster = process_layer(layer, output_prefix, sum_raster)

The Printout:
Processing Point ID: 3, Geometry: Point (459746.35000097844749689 5593918.35010033473372459)
Creating cost grid for layer: amenity_updated, Point ID: 3, Max Reach: 400
Cost raster generated: C:\Users\raven.schmidt\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_kBndzj\d012bd6872844b53b296c3601f226a26\output.nc
Cost raster created for Point ID: 3
Heat values for point: [['0_100', 25.0], ['100_200', 10.0], ['200_300', 5.0], ['300_400', 1.0]]
Processing heat value: Key: 0_100, Value: 25
Recalculating raster amenity_updated 3_0_100_25.0
Summing with existing sum_raster using native:virtualrastercalc
<QgsRasterLayer: 'A + B' (virtualraster)>
<class 'qgis._core.QgsRasterLayer'>
memory:recalculated_raster_3_0_100_25.0
<class 'str'>
Params: {'EXPRESSION': 'A + B', 'LAYERS': [<QgsRasterLayer: 'A + B' (virtualraster)>, 'memory:recalculated_raster_3_0_100_25.0'], 'BANDS': [1, 1], 'OUTPUT': 'memory:sum_result'}
successfull addition

The result's properties:


All rasters have the same CRS, extent and cell size.
QGIS Version is 3.34.11 LTR
Also, assuming I get this fixed, I would like to replace the gdal and grass algorithms with native:virtualrastercalc so I can do everything in memory. For those I used gdal/grass for the same reason, that native:... just didn't accept my input values.

What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

"Does not work" is not a very useful problem description. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact software release in use, the line where the error occurred, and what the error message or other undesirable behavior was.

Do the rasters overlap exactly and have the same pixel size and coordinate system?

I updated my post to adress those point. Sorry for the mess, I'm staring at this problem for days and get more confused by the minute

If they overlap exactly and have the same projections, convert them to numpy arrays, sum and write the output to file
I start with a list of raster files.
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

raster_list = [r"C:\GIS\GIStest\random_rasters\raster1.tif",
                r"C:\GIS\GIStest\random_rasters\raster2.tif",
                r"C:\GIS\GIStest\random_rasters\raster3.tif"]
                
#Read the rasters into numpy arrays
array_list = [] #A list to hold the arrays
for raster_file in raster_list:
    src = gdal.Open(raster_file)
    arr = src.ReadAsArray()
    array_list.append(arr)
    del(src)

summed_array = sum(array_list) #Sum them element wise

#Write to file
out_file = r"C:\GIS\GIStest\random_rasters\summed_rasters.tif"
typemap = {1:gdal.GDT_Byte, 2:gdal.GDT_UInt16, 3:gdal.GDT_Int16, 4:gdal.GDT_UInt32, 5:gdal.GDT_Int32, 6:gdal.GDT_Float32, 7:gdal.GDT_Float64} #From gdal to numpy data types
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
template_raster = gdal.Open(raster_list[0])
template_band = template_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
#Create an empty raster
output = driver.Create(out_file, xsize=template_band.XSize, ysize=template_band.YSize,
    bands=1, eType=typemap[template_band.DataType])
output.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(summed_array) #Fill it
output.SetGeoTransform(template_raster.GetGeoTransform()) #Spatial reference it
output.SetProjection(template_raster.GetProjection())#Set its projection
output=None #Close it
del driver, template_raster, template_band

(If this isnt what you are asking let me know and I'll delete my answer)

Hi Bera, thank you for your reply. This could be a possible solution. However none that allows me to execute all steps in memory. Still, please do not delete your post, I will probably fall back to that.

You dont have to read and write to files if you already have arrays

I have had some success with route through array (if you want to minimize the use of QGIS and GRASS)

This looks like an interesting tool. I will definitely have a look at that
